# undefined is not an object this.props.navigation.navigate react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo

I'm a newbie, and I created a react native app that contains a stack navigator, so I get this error when I click on a button to navigate from one page to another.
the App.js contains the app container:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
        );
  }

}
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Welcome:{
    screen: WelcomeScreen
  },
  SeConnecter: {
    screen:ConnectionScreen} ,
  About : {
    screen: AboutScreen
  },
  list :{
    screen: ListMed
  }, 
});
const screens = {
  Welcome:{ 
    screen : AppDrawerNavigator
  },
  SeConnecter: {
    screen:AppDrawerNavigator
  } ,
  About : {
    screen: AppDrawerNavigator
  },
  list :{
    screen: AppDrawerNavigator
  },   
}
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(screens,{
  defaultNavigationOptions:{
    title: 'MediClic',
    headerTintColor :'#fff',
    headerStyle :{
      backgroundColor:'#3498db',
      height: 100,
    },
    headerTitleStyle :{

      justifyContent:'center',
      fontSize: 30,
      fontFamily: 'serif',
      fontWeight:'bold'

    }

  }
});
const AppNavigator= createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

the welcome screen contains a component search that i created

```
class WelcomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <Search navigation={this.props.navigation}/>

      </View>
    );
  }
export default WelcomeScreen
```

and then the component search where there is a textinput + a search button customized

```
class Search extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render(){

        return(

            <KeyboardAvoidingView style ={styles.main_container} behavior='padding'>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Trouvez votre Medecin!</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.text_input}  placeholder='Médecin,Centre...' />
                <View style={styles.btn_ctr}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={()=>this.navigation.navigate('ListMed') }>
                    <Text style={styles.btn_txt}>Rechercher</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
             </KeyboardAvoidingView>


        )
    }
}
```

Please help me i wasted a lot of times on this, i tried passing the navigation props to  it didn't work

Comment: why `this.navigation.navigate` instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate` from what i can tell class Search does not have a property navigate, `thus this.navigation === undefined`. I don't know much about the StackNavigator so i'm not gonna post it as an answer, but it looks to me like a simple typo

Answer (score 0):

```
<Search navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

as you pass this.props.navigation in navigation on Search component the function call will be - this.props.navigation

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ListMed') }>
```

not `this.navigation.navigate('ListMed')`